# Prolog. Задача на списки

Tags: prolog

(компилятор: `SWI Prolog`)
В числовом списке заменить все вхождения положительных значений на отрицательные элементы этого же списка, проходя список по порядку.
Пример.

```
?-replace_positive([1,-2, 3, -4, -5, 6, 7, 8], X)
X = [-2, -2, -4, -4, -5, -5, 'No', 'No']
```

Пробовал чё-то такое, с бэктрекингом на один шаг назад, но чё-то не выходит

```
 replace_positive([H|T],LN,[H1|R]):- (H < 0), H1 = H, LN1 = H,
 replace_positive(T, LN1, R), H is LN1.
```

Comment: @shkiper, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: понял, исправлюсь

Comment: @alexlz, Если меньше нуля то как есть, иначе берем со второго списка, если он закончился то No. Тут все хорошо.  почему бы не сделать это ответом?

Comment: Небольшое добавление. В ответе.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[[@shkiper](/users/14806/shkiper)](/users/14806/shkiper) может так?

```
t1([], [], []).
t1([X|Y], [X|Z], Q) :- X > 0, t1(Y, Z, Q).
t1([X|Y], Z, [X|Q]) :- X =< 0, t1(Y, Z, Q).
t2([], [], _, []).
t2([XH|XT], Y, Z, [XH|QT]) :- XH < 0, t2(XT, Y, Z, QT).
t2([XH|XT], [XH|YT], [ZH|ZT], [ZH|QT]) :- t2(XT, YT, ZT, QT).
t2([XH|XT], YT, [XH|ZT], [XH|QT]) :- t2(XT, YT, ZT, QT).
t2([XH|XT], [XH|YT], [], ['No'|QT]) :- t2(XT, YT, [], QT).
replace_positive(X, Q) :- t1(X, Y, Z), t2(X, Y, Z, Q).
```

**UPD** Поиск списка положительных значений излишен, поэтому:

```
t1([], []).
t1([X|Y], Q) :- X > 0, t1(Y, Q).
t1([X|Y], [X|Q]) :- X =< 0, t1(Y, Q).
t2([], _, []).
t2([XH|XT], Z, [XH|QT]) :- XH < 0 -> t2(XT, Z, QT).
t2([XH|XT], [ZH|ZT], [ZH|QT]) :- XH >= 0 -> t2(XT, ZT, QT).
t2([XH|XT], [], ['No'|QT]) :- XH > 0 -> t2(XT, [], QT).
replace_positive(X, Q) :- t1(X, Z) -> t2(X, Z, Q).
```